# does monthlyOn() works with between in laravel scheduler?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, php-carbon, laravel-scheduler

I have made a custom command and want it to run on month last day at 02:00 but I also want it to run after that between some period of time like 02:00 till 15:00 following is my scheduler

```
`$schedule->command('billing:generate')
                ->monthlyOn(Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->subHours(5)->format("d"), "02:00");`
```

now what I think Ill do to achieve this is like this:

```
$schedule->command('billing:generate')
            ->monthlyOn(Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->subHours(5)->format("d"), "02:00")
            ->between("02:00", "15:00");
```

will it work as I want? I am on laravel version 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are on Laravel 6, you can schedule your command to run every day, but just check is that day the last day of the month, something like this:

```php
// Runs exactly on "02:00" every month on its last day.
// (Actually runs every day, but doesn't execute if the day is not the last day of the month).
$schedule->command('billing:generate')->dailyAt('02:00')->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});

// Runs between "02:00" and "15:00" every month on its last day. 
// (Actually runs every day, but doesn't execute if the day is not the last day of the month).
$schedule->command('billing:generate')->daily()->between("02:00", "15:00")->when(function () {
    return Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->isToday();
});
```

If you are on newer versions of Laravel you can use `lastDayOfMonth` to which you can provide a time, and if needed, you can also chain `between` on it.

Also, to achieve what you want, you can specify 2 schedules and resolve the problem.

It should be like this:

```php
// Runs exactly on "02:00" every month on its last day. 
$schedule->command('billing:generate')->lastDayOfMonth("02:00");
// Runs between "02:00" and "15:00" every month on its last day. 
$schedule->command('billing:generate')->lastDayOfMonth()->between("02:00", "15:00");
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am on laravel version 6 which does not support lastDayOfMonth()

Comment: I updated the answer to make it Laravel 6 way.

Comment: Ok I will but I have one more thing to ask if I have to use ->withoutOverlapping() where should I put it in?

Comment: You can chain it at the end. It shouldn't start the same new command before the first one is completed. So just add it to the end.